# Merging these two database select queries

Tags: php, mysql

I wonder if there is a way of merging these two database queries so as to have one:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT meta_value FROM ".$wpdb->prefix.
        "postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_cat_num' AND post_id = $var");

$name = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT name FROM ".AH_FEED_DETAILS_TABLE.
        " WHERE id = " . (int)$result->meta_value);

return $name->name;
```

The first query finds the category value which is then used to find the name field in the AH_FEED_DETAILS_TABLE table

Answer (score 2):

You can get the database to do the work for this by using the IN with a sub-query as follows:

```
$name = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT name FROM ".AH_FEED_DETAILS_TABLE.
        " WHERE id IN (SELECT meta_value FROM ".$wpdb->prefix.
        "postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_cat_num' AND post_id = $var)");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $result = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT name FROM ".$wpdb->prefix
                    .AH_FEED_DETAILS_TABLE." AS cat_tbl JOIN postmeta ON 
                    cat_tbl.id=postmeta.meta_value 
                    WHERE postmeta.meta_key = '_cat_num' AND postmeta.post_id = $var");


return $result->name;
```

I hope that helps giving the idea